# Insert into database table with if else statement in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms

May be i didn't ask well
Let's say i have two forms

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="reg_as" id="export" value="exporter">
    <input type="submit" name="reg">
</form>

<form action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="reg_as" id="import" value="importer">
    <input type="submit" name="reg">
</form>
```

How do i insert into multiple tables with if else conditions
**reg.php**

```
$reg_as = strip_tags(@$_POST['reg_as']);
$reg = strip_tags(@$_POST['reg']);
$exporter = "exporter";
$importer = "importer";

if ($reg)
{
    if ($reg_as == $exporter)
                    {
                        $sql =<<<EOF
INSERT INTO exporter (reg_as) 
VALUES ('$reg_as');
EOF;

                        $stmt = $db->exec($sql);

                        if (!$stmt)
                        {
                            echo "<script>alert('There was an error some where!.. Please try again')</script>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            header("Location: index.php");
                        }
                        if ($reg_as == $importer) {
                            $sql = <<<EOF
INSERT INTO importer (reg_as) 
VALUES ('$reg_as');
EOF;
                        }

                        $stmt = $db->exec($sql);

                        if (!$stmt)
                        {
                            echo "<script>alert('There was an error some where!.. Please try again')</script>";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            header("Location: index.php");
                        }

}
```

The issue here is that, the data dosn't insert to database. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: You're assigning `=` rather than comparing `==`.

Comment: `"I am aware of the security risk of the php code so please ignore that part"` - What if that part is what's causing a problem?  When your code isn't working in some way, assuring us that everything is fine and doesn't need to be corrected is *not* a particularly effective way to diagnose and solve the problem.

Comment: This guy **Hubert Blaine   Wolfeschlegelsteinhausenbergerdorff**   would never be able to signup on your system

Answer (score 1):

This is an assignment, and the expression returns `bool(true)`:

`if ($reg_as = "Exporter")`

To compare the two values, you should use two equal signs:

`if ($reg_as == "Exporter")`

Maybe your could do something like this:

```
<form action="reg.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="importer">Importer</option>
        <option value="exporter">Exporter</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="reg_as" placeholder="Insert your data here..." />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
</form>

<?php

if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $type = in_array($_POST['type'], ['exporter', 'importer']) ? $_POST['type'] : false;
    $value = $_POST['reg_as'];

    switch ($type) {
        case 'exporter':
            $query = "INSERT INTO exporter (reg_as) VALUES (:reg_as)";
            break;
        case 'importer':
            $query = "INSERT INTO importer (reg_as) VALUES (:reg_as)";
            break;
        default:
            throw new Exception('Handle your error here!');
            break;
    }

    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $insert = $statement->execute([':reg_as' => $value]);

    if ($insert) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('There was an error some where!.. Please try again')</script>";
    }
}
```

Comment: You right. That's part of the problem. I edited my question please help because the data doesn't insert to database

Comment: Both of your fields are named `reg_as` but in your code your requesting `reg_as` and `reg`.

Comment: Yea. `reg` is the submit input (for submitting the form)

Comment: @TegaOke I've edited the answer.